# Parsing html table containing images to datatable attribute

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, winforms, html-table

i used the following code to parse html table inner text to datatable (using Html-Agility-Pack):

```
    Imports System.Net

    Public Sub ParseHtmlTable(byval HtmlFilePath as String)

    Dim webStream As Stream
    Dim webResponse = ""
    Dim req As FileWebRequest
    Dim res As FileWebResponse

    ' REQUEST PAGE (We are requesting Google Finance Page with NSE:RENUKA Stock Info

    req = WebRequest.Create("file:///" & HtmlFilePath)



    req.Method = "GET" ' Method of sending HTTP Request(GET/POST)

    res = req.GetResponse ' Send Request

    webStream = res.GetResponseStream() ' Get Response

    Dim webStreamReader As New StreamReader(webStream)

    Dim htmldoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    htmldoc.LoadHtml(webStreamReader.ReadToEnd())

    Dim nodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr")

    Dim dtTable As New DataTable("Table1")

    Dim Headers As List(Of String) = nodes(0).Elements("th").Select(Function(x) x.InnerText.Trim).ToList

    For Each Hr In Headers

        dtTable.Columns.Add(Hr)

    Next


    For Each node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In nodes

        Dim Row = node.Elements("td").Select(Function(x) x.InnerText.Trim).ToArray

        dtTable.Rows.Add(Row)

    Next


    dtTable.WriteXml("G:\1.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

    End Sub
```

How to parse an html table containing images to a Datatable and saving images as binary or saving their links using VB.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally. images look like:

```
<img src="img.jpg"/>
```

We can use

```
.SelectNodes("./img").Attributes("src").Value()
```

To return the image path on the node containing it